# How to Prompt user with permission dialog in iframe application

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs, xfbml

I am using

Facebook.showPermissionDialog("read_stream,publish_stream, offline_access, email") to show permission dialog. Its working in FBML mode but the problem is in IFRAME mode.

The below code also works fine in FBML mode but not in Iframe mode.

fb:prompt-permission perms="read_stream,publish_stream, offline_access, email">Allow Access?

Please help me regarding this..

I need to display Prompt permission dialog in IFRAME mode

Thanks in advance,
Ibrahim.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog) instead.

Comment: What Karol said — FBML is now officially deprecated, so it's worth learning how to build functionality using the Facebook JavaScript API in any case.